# Somehow UI font looks skinny in 15.10

Tags: graphics, fonts, 15.10

https://i.stack.imgur.com/It7Jr.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz4eW.png

Fonts looks weird in menu bar and dash and normal in other places.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would probably be to install `unity-tweak-tool` using `apt-get`. From there you can change the settings of the fonts used, including the thickness.